# How to give link for 3 different URLs on single button using select list in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

If user selects one option from select list then that button should link to different URL, if user selects second option from that select list then that same button should land at another URL , Kindly help me in it using ORACLE APEX.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a page item P1_URL of type select list
- Add a couple of entries - for this example I'm using static values but a query should work too. Make sure the return value of the entry contains the actual url:

[image]

- Create a button with action "Submit Page"
- Create a branch

  - Execution Options > Point > "Processing"
  - Type: "Url defined by Item (Redirect)"
  - Item: P1_URL

Run the page, when you click the button the page should redirect to the selected url.